# How can I create a live blog with Wordpress.com?

Tags: wordpress.com

I would like to create a live blog with my Wordpress.com blog. I realize that Automattic have recently [created a plugin to do this](http://vip.wordpress.com/liveblog-add-on/), but this is only for VIP members and I don't have [the space $10,000 lying around](http://vip.wordpress.com/our-services/) to do this.

I could go self-hosted, but I'm just getting started with the blog so I want to keep it as cheap to maintain as possible. Is there any way that I can live blog using my Wordpress.com blog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't install plugins on a hosted WordPress site, neither can you run arbitrary JavaScript code. With these restrictions, there's no way that you can live blog on your hosted WordPress.com blog